# Is it advisable to upgrade to Django 1.5?

Tags: django, django-1.5

I'm currently using 1.4.3. 1.5 will make my front-end development much easier because of the new verbatim template tag.

The release candidate was posted a few weeks ago: https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/jan/04/15-rc-1/

Is it advisable to upgrade? Where can I find a build status or see outstanding bugs or anything else that's holding up the final release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is mostly a judgment call based on your project requirements and your schedule.  Technically, I consider 1.5 to be pretty good and the improvements, especially to user model extension, to be invaluable.  But it's still under development and bugs are still being found.

If you are developing an app that you don't plan to launch within a month, I would definitely upgrade.  I like the new 1.5 features and it will probably be officially released fairly soon.

If you are developing an app that you need to launch sooner than that in a high-stress environment, I would pass on upgrading until after 1.5 is stable.

If you are developing an app that isn't going to see heavy use very soon, then you could go either way, but I would lean towards upgrading.

Comment: This is what i was going to say. Also, you could take a look at verbatim code if you wanna replicate it until 1.5 is released (because you can't upgrade because of some of Andrew's reasons): https://github.com/django/django/blob/a7b7d6320c6838e884778c92a0d478b6df980628/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1293

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I ran my test suite against 1.5 and it failed horribly. A lot of stuff is deprecated including generic views (I haven't adopted CBVs yet) and other things, like with the {% url tag, etc.

Comment: Good on you, to have a test suite that can tell you these things!  Proceed with caution.